# Function App PowerShell - Publish Function with Module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-functions

Got a weird issue publishing a PowerShell Function to a Function App. The Function App uses Windows consumption with a Y1 App Service Plan.

The Function uses 5 different Az Modules that exist in the Modules Directory as part of the Package:

- Az.Accounts
- Az.Resources
- Az.Compute
- Az.Sql
- Az.SqlVirtualMachine

The File structure looks like this:

```
wwwroot/
| - .funcignore
| - ahubReporter
| | - function.json
| | - readme.md
| | - run.ps1
| - host.json
| - Modules
| | - Az.Accounts
| | - Az.Compute
| | - Az.Resources
| | - Az.Sql
| | - Az.SqlVirtualMachine
| - profile.ps1
| - requirements.psd1
```

> NOTE: `managedDependency` is not enabled and the `Az` Modules are not download automatically. The Modules are included in the source under the `Modules` directory and published with the function

If the Function is published manually through vscode using the Azure Function Extension, the function works and runs perfectly.

However, If I publish the Function by either the Azure DevOps Task `AzureFunctionApp@2` or Azure PowerShell Task AzurePowerShell@5 using the command `Publish-AzWebApp`, the function is published, but does not run and I get the following error:

```
The 'Get-AzLocation' command was found in the module 'Az.Resources', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Resources'.
```

The Azure DevOps Pipeline is configured to use a Windows Agent.

The Azure DevOps Task AzureFunctionApp@2 is:

```yaml
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Publish Function | package'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.customerServiceConnection }}
    appType: functionApp
    appName: $(functionName)
    package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip
    deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage' # <--- I've tried auto as well
```

The Azure DevOps Task AzurePowerShell@5 is:

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Publish Function | azpwsh'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.customerServiceConnection }}
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $(functionAppRg) -Name $(functionName) -ArchivePath $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip -Force'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
     pwsh: true
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run : Import-Module Az.Resources

Comment: yes, doesn't work. The Module is already imported, but for some reason when the function is published via vscode - it's fine, but not when publish via the Azure DevOps task or PowerShell Publish-AzWebApp

Comment: Try troubleshooting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a little as the error messages suggests that the `PSModulePath` is not configured correctly as it can locate the function/cmdlet and the module but it's not able to load it.

It is my understanding that the `Modules` folder in the root of the project is appended to the PSModulePath when the worker is initialised.

I quickly built a project in a devcontainer to do some tests, disabled managed dependencies as you advised.

Ran `Save-Module` to save the `Az.Resources` module and added it to a Modules folder within the project.

When running the project you can see the logs in a bit better detail than you get from AzDo or the portal and there are a large amount of errors coming from the internal commands within `Az.Resources` & `Az.Accounts` there are also internal modules `Az.Authorisation` & `Az.MsGraph` which show in the logs with Newtonsoft collision errors.

```
 Message        : The 'Get-AzLocation' command was found in the module 'Az.Resources', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Resources'.
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.599Z]     Data           : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.599Z]     InnerException : 
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.599Z]         Type           : System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.599Z]         ErrorRecord    : 
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.599Z]             Exception             : 
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.599Z]                 Type       : System.IO.FileLoadException
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.600Z]                 Message    : Assembly with same name is already loaded
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.600Z]                 TargetSite : 
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.600Z]                     Name          : Bind_LoadAssemblies
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.600Z]                     DeclaringType : initialsessionstate
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.600Z]                     MemberType    : Method
[2023-06-09T10:22:21.600Z]                     Module        : System.Management.Automation.dll
```

I pushed the project to Github here so you can see the errors it generates

https://github.com/brettmillerb/stackoverflowTest

Out of curiosity have you tried using the Azure Functions Deploy v2 task instead of a powershell task and using the PowerShell equivalent?

```yaml
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: Azure Function App Deploy
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appName: samplefunctionapp
    appType: functionApp
    package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-app-v2?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: Thanks, yes I've tried both with the same result. something is different when publishing the function using vscode.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Looks like there is conflict loading it. You've given me some ideas - I'll come back to you. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of adding your Powershell Modules in a separate Module folder, Directly add them in requirements.psd1 folder, the requirements.psd1 will automatically download those packages for you.

I ran one Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy Azure Powershell HTTP Trigger and it was successful, Refer below:-

**My repository:-**

[image]

[image]

**requirements.psd1**

```
@{
    'Az' = '9.*'
    'Az.Accounts' = '1.1.0'
    'Az.Compute' = '0.5.0'
    'Az.Resources' = '6.7.0'
    'Az.Sql' = '4.7.0'
    'Az.SqlVirtualMachine' = '2.0.0'
}
```

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxx-52801a7de72a'

  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc5431'


  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - powershell: |
        if (Test-Path "extensions.csproj") {
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./$(workingDirectory)/bin
        }
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(functionAppName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

[image]

If you want to run the module files, Make sure you Import or Install them in a Powershell task like below and then run your Function Publish task.

```
Import-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.Resources -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.Compute -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.Sql -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.SqlVirtualMachine -Force
```

If still the error persists, Run your Pipeline by enabling diagnostics or by adidng --Verbose flag at the end of your Powershell command like below:-

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Publish Function | azpwsh'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.customerServiceConnection }}
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $(functionAppRg) -Name $(functionName) -ArchivePath $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip -Force -Verbose'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    pwsh: true
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using the requirements.psd1 to install the modules I need, but it's very slow, hence why I opted to bundle the modules with the function. It's just so weird that it works publishing the function with vscode, but not with the AzDo tasks.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it working.

Although, I still don't understand why it wouldn't work using the Azure DevOps Task `AzureFunctionApp@2` or the Azure PowerShell Task `AzurePowerShell@5` using the command `Publish-AzWebApp`, but it would if it was published via `vscode`.

Basically, I streamlined the code (I didn't write originally), removed the modules and updated the following files:

#### host.json

Enabled `managedDependency`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "managedDependency": {
    "enabled": true // <----- This
  }
}
```

#### requirements.psd1

Removed `'Az' = '10.*'` and added the following:

```
@{
    'Az.Accounts' = '2.12.3'
    'Az.Compute' = '6.0.0'
    'Az.Resources' = '6.7.0'
    'Az.Sql' = '4.7.0'
    'Az.SqlVirtualMachine' = '2.0.0'
}
```

Thanks for all in responding. Everyone gave me some ideas and I just ended up trying different configurations and enhancing the original code.

Thanks!